# How to get autofocus work when textarea loads in internet explorer

Tags: jquery

Autofocus doesn't work in internet explorer neither works using jquery focus() method after finishing loading textarea.

How can i get it work in internet explorer?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input name="email" type="text" placeholder="joe@contoso.com " autofocus />
```

and you can read more 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441087(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

the jquery focus method should work... Could you send your code ?
Here a working sample :

```
<textarea id="mytext" ></textarea>
<script>
$(function() {
  $("#mytext").focus();
});
</script>
```

Comment: $('#textarea').on('ready', function () {
     $(this).focus();
});
OR 
$(function() {
$('#sharingtextarea').focus();
});

Comment: My code is the same as your second one.I think there is a mispelling in the name of uour textarea : why call it with an id textarea in one case and with an id sharingtextarea in the other? Make sure you use the correct id after the #...